# How could I transfer files to a PC, but not allow to download them again?

Tags: windows, file-management, file-transfer

I'm looking for suggestions on setting up a Windows 7 PC so that a remote worker can upload any type of file TO the PC, but must never be able to download or transfer any files *from* the PC, including any files they previously uploaded.

So basically a one-way file transfer system.

Comment: it something like hack, you are looking for...

Answer (score 1):

You could set a directory with write-only permissions, and not allow the users to view the contents. Unless they knew the exact filename, it would be difficult to copy a file out. You could also run a rename script every time a file is copied in to add some long random sequence to the filename so a user cannot just guess the name of a file, or know the name of a file they copied in.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way working on all versions of the OS would be to share one directory (to receive the files) and to schedule a script to move the files to another (not shared) directory regularly (or as soon as the first is not empty).

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the folder and click the Properties.
2. Go to Security tab.
3. Go to Advanced option.
4. Here you can very well select the options you want the people to have when the file is shared. Namely for your requirement "WRITE ONLY".